# Bash: for in loop with brace expansion in list

Tags: bash, loops, brace-expansion

I would like to write a for in loop in which the possible values are taken from another variable. The part that I can't figure out is how to include values that need brace expansion. For example:

```
TEXT="a b c d{a..c} e f"
for VAR in $TEXT; do echo $VAR; done
```

What i get is

```
a
b
c
d{a..c}
e
f
```

But what I want is

```
a
b
c
da
db
dc
e
f
```

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fear that you may have to resort to using `eval` in this case...However, I'd suggest that you avoided using a loop:

```
eval "printf '%s\n' $TEXT"
```

Using `eval` means that the braces will be expanded, producing your desired outcome.

You can see what happens using `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ eval "printf '%s\n' $TEXT"
+ eval 'printf '\''%s\n'\'' a b c d{a..c} e f'
++ printf '%s\n' a b c da db dc e f
a
b
c
da
db
dc
e
f
```

Note that the expansion occurs before the list is passed as arguments to `printf`.

If you get to define `$TEXT` yourself and want to loop through each of its expanded elements, I'd suggest using an array instead:

```
text=( a b c d{a..c} e f )
for var in "${text[@]}"; do
    # whatever with "$var"
done
```

This is the preferred solution as it doesn't involve using `eval`.

Comment: The solution with the array works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Agreed, arrays are the way to go here ([some reasons why eval is problematic for the curious](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/3149036))

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

While there's a time & place for `eval`, it's not the safest approach for the general case. See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/3149036) for some reasons why.

---

Use [`eval`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23111):

```
TEXT="a b c d{a..c} e f"
for VAR in $TEXT; do eval echo $VAR; done
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
da db dc
e
f
```

If you want to loop over every element, you'll have to nest your loops:

```
for VAR in $TEXT; do
  for VAR2 in $(eval echo $VAR); do
    echo $VAR2
  done
done
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
da
db
dc
e
f
```

Or use the eval on `TEXT` rather than each element:

```
TEXT="$(eval echo "a b c d{a..c} e f")"
for VAR in $TEXT; do echo $VAR; done
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
da
db
dc
e
f
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Without `eval`, but with command substitution:

```
$ text="$(echo a b c d{a..c} e f)"
$ echo "$text"
a b c da db dc e f
```

And, as mentioned in Tom's answer, an array is probably the better way to go here.